# I want to change the timezone and the sender of the appointment in Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, com-automation

I want to change the timezone of the start date and end date to CST (US/Central Time), the time I am encoding here automatically translates to local time so it changes after putting it in the `appointment.Start = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`  to local time.
I also wanted to know how could I change the sender of this appointment to a gmail that I will provide. Because `appointment.Organizer = "gmail"` does not works nor `appointment.SendUsingAccount = "gmail"` does not

Here is the code:

```py
acc = ""
for account in session.Accounts:
    if account.AccountType == 1: #0 - outlookExchange, 1 - outlookIMAP, 2 - outlookPop3
        print(account)
        acc = account

def saveMeeting(start, end, subject, location, attachments, recipients):

    appointment = outlook.CreateItem(1) #1 - AppointmentItem

    # Fill in the data needed
    appointment.SendUsingAccount = acc
    appointment.StartTimeZone = outlook.TimeZones("Central Standard Time")
    appointment.Start = start #yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
    appointment.EndTimeZone = outlook.TimeZones("Central Standard Time")
    appointment.End = end #yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
    appointment.Subject = subject
    appointment.Location = location
    appointment.MeetingStatus = 1 

    if attachments != '':
        appointment.Attachments.Add(attachments)

    recipients = filter(None, recipients)

    for recipient in recipients:
        appointment.Recipients.Add(recipient) 

    appointment.Save()

    # Only use .Display() if using tkinter
    appointment.Display()
```

Comment: I found a similar entry here [link](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.office.developer.outlook.vba/c/9WxVPZiEv9I?pli=1), but the thing is that this is a `MailItem`, the one that I am using is an `AppointmentItem`. Again, `appointment.SendUsingAccount = "gmail@gmail.com` does not change the Appointment `from` field/value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a time zone you need to use the [TimeZones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.timezones?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=outlook-pia) interface which represents all the time zones recognized in Microsoft Windows. It also uses the `TimeZone` object to set or get the `StartTimeZone` property and the `EndTimeZone` property on the `AppointmentItem` object. Here is the sample VB code which shows how to set a time zone in Outlook appointments:

```
Private Sub TimeZoneExample()
    Dim appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem = _
        CType(Application.CreateItem( _
        Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem), Outlook.AppointmentItem)
    Dim tzs As Outlook.TimeZones = Application.TimeZones
    ' Obtain timezone using indexer and locale-independent key
    Dim tzEastern As Outlook.TimeZone = tzs("Eastern Standard Time")
    Dim tzPacific As Outlook.TimeZone = tzs("Pacific Standard Time")
    appt.Subject = "SEA - JFK Flight"
    appt.Start = DateTime.Parse("8/9/2006 8:00 AM")
    appt.StartTimeZone = tzPacific
    appt.End = DateTime.Parse("8/9/2006 5:30 PM")
    appt.EndTimeZone = tzEastern
    appt.Display(False)
End Sub
```

If you have got your `gmail` account configured in Outlook profile you can use the [AppointmentItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.sendusingaccount) property.

Here is VBA sample which shows how to set up the `SendUsingAccount` property in Outlook:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
     Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com")  
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll  
     Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount  
     oMail.Send  
   End If  
 Next  
End Sub
```

Comment: Do i just used `SendUsingAccount` like a normal variable? Or is there a way for me to set it? Like using a getter?

Also, the timezones part, do i also need to use `DateTime.Parse` in Python? In what what could I import that?

ps. I am new to this stuff sorry

Comment: I could make the timezone work now, but the problem is that the String as start and end that i pass turns into a local time, so it adjusts based on the timezone I set, I just want them to remain the same, but just change the time zone in outlook.

`SendUsingAcount` does not work, it does not change the `from` field in outlook

Comment: I've just included the sample code which shows how to set up the `SendUsingAcount` property.

Comment: I just tried it with AppointmentItem but it doesn't seem to change the Account, it stays at the default account. In AppointmentItem, instead of using olPop3, i used olImap. (I tried both, nothing worked)

Comment: I edited my code where I tried to use the `SendUsingAccount`

Comment: So, i tried using normal mail, it worked, but for the AppointmentItem, it does not change the `from` value. My account is already configured in the outlook, and I could access the account from `Application.Session.Accounts`. The problem is that I could not change the account. Can u help me with this?

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question separately in a new thread.